# Getter for a block on a class?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, block

I am creating a property on a class that is gonna be a block.

It is being defined like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^ myBlock)();
```

I would like to do lazy creation of that property, so I want to create a getter for that block to run when the the property is used by some code.

If the property was not a block and was a NSArray for example, I would do the setter like this:

```
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty;

- (NSArray *)myProperty {

    if (_myProperty) {
        _myProperty = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }

    return _myProperty;
}
```

How do I do a getter (lazy instantiation) for a property that is a block?

NOTE: this block is inside a singleton.

thanks

Comment: your NSArray example is not a setter

Comment: ah, sorry about that. My english sucks.... any idea on how to do that for a block?

Comment: you wanna find out how to get a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^ myBlock)();

- (void (^)())myBlock {
    if (!_myBlock) {
        self.myBlock = ^ () {
            NSLog(@"Do something");
        };
    }
    return _myBlock;
}
```

Comment: ahhhh... why copy and not strong?

Comment: Block has only two functions  
Block_copy();
Block_release(); Сopy specifier just makes the code more understandable

Comment: blocks are always copied internally

Comment: ok. Thanks. What about this self.block = ... isn't the correct likely to be _myBlock = ... ?

Comment: _myBlock = ... will work only in ARC-mode. In non-arc your block will be autoreleased.

Comment: @ShimanskiArtem: "In non-arc your block will be autoreleased" No, in non-ARC mode, without copying it, you would have a stack block, which is not memory managed at all (it cannot be retained or autoreleased). It just ceases to exist and you would be returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: self.block uses the property, _block accesses the variable directly. former is better (e.g. for later subclassing)

Comment: @newacct, you right. I said a little wrong. All related variables will be autoreleased, not the block itself.

Answer (score 1):

in h

```
typedef BOOL (^MyProcessorBlock)(id param1);

@property (nonatomic, copy) MyProcessorBlock myBlockProperty
```

in m (if you use old objc pre 2.0, pre summer 2012)

```
@synthesize myBlockProperty = _myBlockProperty;
```

in any case in m file

```
- (MyBlock)myBlockProperty {
    if(!_myBlockProperty) {
        _myBlockProperty = ^(self) { ..... };
    }
    return _myBlockProperty;
}
```

Comment: "if you use old objc" which old objc? you seem to be taking advantage of ARC, which is not that old

Comment: new = summer 2012 -- where you dont need a synthesize anymore :) [the change that also brought literals] edited the code